# numpy bincount - choose the max weight instead of sum all weights

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Is it possible to use `np.bincount` but get the max instead of sum of weights? Here, `bbb` at index `3` has two values, `11.1` and `55.5`. I want to have `55.5`, not `66.6`. I doubt I choose use other function but not so sure which one is good for this purpose.

```
bbb = np.array([ 3, 7, 11, 13, 3])
weight = np.array([ 11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 44.4, 55.5])
print np.bincount(bbb, weight, minlength=15)

OUT >> [  0.    0.    0.   66.6   0.    0.    0.   22.2   0.    0.    0.   33.3   0.   44.4   0. ]
```

Note that, in fact, `bbb` and `weight` are very large (about `5e6` elements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [solution to your 2D question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47526176/636626) is also valid for the 1D case, so you can use `np.maxmimum.at`

```
out = np.zeros(15)
np.maximum.at(out, bbb, weight)
# array([  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,  55.5,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,  22.2,   0. ,
#          0. ,   0. ,  33.3,   0. ,  44.4,   0. ])
```

Comment: Looks better on bigger arrays indeed.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1 :** Here's one way with [`np.maximum.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) to get the binned maximum values -

```
def binned_max(bbb, weight, minlength):
    sidx = bbb.argsort()
    weight_s = weight[sidx]
    bbb_s = bbb[sidx]
    cut_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate(([True], bbb_s[1:] != bbb_s[:-1])))
    bbb_unq = bbb_s[cut_idx]
    #Or bbb_unq, cut_idx = np.unique(bbb_s, return_index=1)
    max_val = np.maximum.reduceat(weight_s, cut_idx)
    out = np.zeros(minlength, dtype=weight.dtype)
    out[bbb_unq] = max_val
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [36]: bbb = np.array([ 3, 7, 11, 13, 3])
    ...: weight = np.array([ 11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 44.4, 55.5])

In [37]: binned_max(bbb, weight, minlength=15)
Out[37]: 
array([  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,  55.5,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,  22.2,   0. ,
         0. ,   0. ,  33.3,   0. ,  44.4,   0. ])
```

---

**Approach #2 :** Well I was trying to check out/having fun with `numba` to solve this and it seems quite efficient. Here's one numba way -

```
from numba import njit 

@njit
def numba_func(out, bins, weight, minlength):
    l = len(bins)
    for i in range(l):
        if out[bins[i]] < weight[i]:
            out[bins[i]] = weight[i]
    return out

def maxat_numba(bins, weight, minlength):
    out = np.zeros(minlength, dtype=weight.dtype)
    out[bins] = weight.min()
    numba_func(out, bins, weight, minlength)
    return out
```

Runtime test -

The built-in with `np.maximum.at` looks quite neat and would be the preferred one in most scenarios, so testing the proposed one against it -

```
# @Nils Werner's soln with np.maximum.at
def maxat_numpy(bins, weight, minlength):
    out = np.zeros(minlength)
    np.maximum.at(out, bins, weight)
    return out
```

Timings -

Case #1 :

```
In [155]: bbb = np.random.randint(1,1000, (10000))

In [156]: weight = np.random.rand(*bbb.shape)

In [157]: %timeit maxat_numpy(bbb, weight, minlength=bbb.max()+1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 686 µs per loop

In [158]: %timeit maxat_numba(bbb, weight, minlength=bbb.max()+1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.6 µs per loop
```

Case #2 :

```
In [159]: bbb = np.random.randint(1,10000, (1000000))

In [160]: weight = np.random.rand(*bbb.shape)

In [161]: %timeit maxat_numpy(bbb, weight, minlength=bbb.max()+1)
10 loops, best of 3: 66 ms per loop

In [162]: %timeit maxat_numba(bbb, weight, minlength=bbb.max()+1)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.42 ms per loop
```

Comment: How does `np.maximum.reduceat(weight_s, cut_idx)` work here? By the way, if the array is large, will `argsort()` quite slow?

Comment: @Jan Linked docs on `numpy.ufunc.reduceat` should help clarify. We can't use this `reduceat` without `sorting`, so that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not quite as fast as the answer by Nils, but the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) has a more flexible syntax for performing these type of operations:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique_keys, maxima_per_key = npi.group_by(bbb).max(weight)
```