# Fast way to fill matrix from np.array of row index, column index, and max(values)

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I have quite large arrays to fill matrix (about `5e6` elements). I know the fast way to fill is something like

(simplified example)

```
bbb = (np.array([1,2,3,4,1])) # row
ccc = (np.array([0,1,2,1,0])) # column
ddd = (np.array([55.5,22.2,33.3,44.4,11.1])) # values

experiment = np.zeros(shape=(5,3))
experiment[bbb, ccc] = [ddd] # filling
>[[  0.    0.    0. ]
 [ 11.1   0.    0. ]
 [  0.   22.2   0. ]
 [  0.    0.   33.3]
 [  0.   44.4   0. ]]
```

but if I want the max `ddd` instead. Something like at `# filling`

```
#pseudocode
experiment[bbb, ccc] = [ddd if ddd > experiment[bbb, ccc]]
```

The matrix should return

```
>[[  0.    0.    0. ]
 [ 55.5   0.    0. ]
 [  0.   22.2   0. ]
 [  0.    0.   33.3]
 [  0.   44.4   0. ]]
```

What is a good fast way to get max to fill the matrix from np.array here?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. How do you arrive at your last matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.ufunc.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) on [`np.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html).

`np.ufunc.at` performs the preceding `ufunc` "unbuffered and in-place". This means all indices appearing in `[bbb, ccc]` will be processed by `np.maximum`, no matter how ofthen those indices appear.

In your case `(0, 1)` appears twice, so it will be processed twice, each time picking the maximum of `experiment[bbb, ccc]` and `ddd`.

```
np.maximum.at(experiment, [bbb, ccc], ddd)
# array([[  0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
#        [ 55.5,   0. ,   0. ],
#        [  0. ,  22.2,   0. ],
#        [  0. ,   0. ,  33.3],
#        [  0. ,  44.4,   0. ]])
```