# tf.math.bincount - use min/max weight instead of weight sum

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to get a max/min value in `tf.math.bincount` instead of the weight sum. Basically currently it works as:

```
values = tf.constant([1,1,2,3,2,4,4,5])
weights = tf.constant([1,5,0,1,0,5,4,5])
tf.math.bincount(values, weights=weights) #[0 6 0 1 9 5]
```

However, I would like to get max/min for the conflicting weights instead, e.g. for max it should return:
`[0 5 0 1 5 5]`

Comment: do you need a solution that strictly uses tensorflow/keras functions?

Comment: yes, I can solve it using pure python fns and iterative programming, but have troubles to come up with 'tricks' of how to solve it in TF/Keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires some finessing, but you can accomplish this as follows:

```
def bincount_with_max_weight(values: tf.Tensor, weights: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    _range = tf.range(tf.reduce_max(values) + 1)
    return tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.maximum(
        tf.reduce_max(tf.gather(weights, tf.where(tf.equal(values, x)))), 0), _range)
```

The output for the example case is:

```
[0 5 0 1 5 5]
```

Breaking it down, the first line computes the range of values in `values`:

```
_range = tf.range(tf.reduce_max(values) + 1)
```

and in the second line, the maximum of `weight` is computed per element in `_range` using `tf.map_fn` with `tf.where`, which retrieves indices where the clause is true, and `tf.gather`, which retrieves the values corresponding to supplied indices.

The `tf.maximum` wraps the output to handle the case where the element does not exist in `values` i.e; in the example case, `0` does not exist in `values` so the output without `tf.maximum` would be `INT_MIN` for 0:

```
[-2147483648           5           0           1           5           5]
```

This could also be applied on the final result tensor instead of per element:

```
def bincount_with_max_weight(values: tf.Tensor, weights: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    _range = tf.range(tf.reduce_max(values) + 1)
    result = tf.map_fn(lambda x:
                       tf.reduce_max(tf.gather(weights, tf.where(tf.equal(values, x)))), _range)
    return tf.maximum(result, 0)
```

Note that this would not work if negative weights are utilized - in that case, `tf.where` can be used for comparing against the minimum integer value (`tf.int32.min` in the example, although this can be applied for any numeric dtype) instead of applying `tf.maximum`:

```
def bincount_with_max_weight(values: tf.Tensor, weights: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    _range = tf.range(tf.reduce_max(values) + 1)
    result = tf.map_fn(lambda x:
                       tf.reduce_max(tf.gather(weights, tf.where(tf.equal(values, x)))), _range)
    return tf.where(tf.equal(result, tf.int32.min), 0, result)
```

## Update

For handling the 2D Tensor case, we can use `tf.map_fn` to apply the maximum weight function to each pair of values and weights in the batch:

```
def bincount_with_max_weight(values: tf.Tensor, weights: tf.Tensor, axis: Optional[int] = None) -> tf.Tensor:
    _range = tf.range(tf.reduce_max(values) + 1)

    def mapping_function(x: int, _values: tf.Tensor, _weights: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
        return tf.reduce_max(tf.gather(_weights, tf.where(tf.equal(_values, x))))

    if axis == -1:
        result = tf.map_fn(lambda pair: tf.map_fn(lambda x: mapping_function(x, *pair), _range), (values, weights),
                           dtype=tf.int32)
    else:
        result = tf.map_fn(lambda x: mapping_function(x, values, weights), _range)
    return tf.where(tf.equal(result, tf.int32.min), 0, result)
```

For the 2D example provided:

```
    values = tf.constant([[1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 4, 5]])
    weights = tf.constant([[1, 5, 0, 1], [0, 5, 4, 5]])
    print(bincount_with_max_weight(values, weights, axis=-1))
```

The output is:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 5 0 1 0 0]
 [0 5 0 0 4 5]], shape=(2, 6), dtype=int32)
```

This implementation is a generalization of the approach originally described - if `axis` is omitted, it will compute results for the 1D case.

Comment: Thanks, I think it would work, however it doesn't support 2d tensors e.g. if I have batches of data. With bincount I could set axis= -1:
values = tf.constant([[1,1,2,3],
                      [2,1,4,5]])
weights = tf.constant([[1,5,0,1],
                       [0,5,4,5]])
tf.math.bincount(values, weights=weights, axis=-1

Comment: @Le_Coeur Added an update for handling 2D.

Answer (score 1):

For Faster Execution try this,

```
values = tf.constant([[1,1,2,3], [2,1,4,5]]) 
weights = tf.constant([[1,5,0,1], [0,5,4,5]])

def find_max_bins(output , values , weights):

  np.maximum.at(output , values , weights)
  return output
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype = tf.float32),
                              tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype = tf.int32),
                              tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype = tf.int32)
                              ])
def tf_function(output , values , weights):
  print(values)
  y = tf.numpy_function(find_max_bins, [output , values , weights], tf.float32)
  return y

length = np.max(values)+1
initial_value = [0 for x in range(length)]
variable = tf.Variable(initial_value = initial_value, shape=(length) , dtype=tf.float32)

for i , (value , weight) in enumerate(zip(values , weights)):
  if(i > 0):
    output = tf.stack([output , tf_function(variable , value , weight)] , 0)
  else:
    output = tf_function(variable , value , weight)
  variable.assign_sub(initial_value)
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 6), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 5., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 5., 0., 0., 4., 5.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it is different to what I'm trying to achieve. I found the exact same functionality that I would like in TF, but in numpy (np.maximum.at) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525773/numpy-bincount-choose-the-max-weight-instead-of-sum-all-weights

Comment: Yeah, maybe I have not gotten your point, about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I simplified the question based on the existing tf functionality

Comment: Use Pandas for keeping things simple,

df = pd.DataFrame(np.stack((values , weights)).T)
df.groupby([0]).max()

The output would be the same as mentioned before this will also work for 2D Matrices. You don't need to write 10 lines of code.

Comment: I agree, using Pandas is a viable solution as well, but the original question requested an implementation which utilizes the TF/Keras API. Also, while there are some threads discussing how `tf.map_fn` works with CPU and GPU, the TF implementation proposed could use GPU for some operations, whereas Pandas will be limited to CPU unless CuDF or something similar is used.